# Jmeter Variable: How to convert there variables $269,768 and 269768.0 to 269768

Tags: jmeter

How to convert these JMeter variables $269,768 and 269768.0 to 269768

is there any syntax in beanshell processors I can use

Answer (score 0):

[Since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so I'll provide a Groovy-based solution:

1. For converting `$269,768` to `269768` you need to use [NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class like

   ```
   def format = java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale('en', "US"))
   format.setMaximumFractionDigits(3)

   def foo = format.parse(vars.get('your_variable_here').substring(1))
   ```
2. For converting `269768.0` to `269768` just cast it to [Double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) first, then to [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)

   ```
   def bar = vars.get('your_variable_here') as double as int
   ```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)